# how to take color screenshot using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webpage-screenshot

screenshots is getting captured like below images but i want to capture it in actual colors also i don't know the reason behind it can anybody tell me why this is happening?

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,131)");
 int yPosition = Decision_Maker.getLocation().getY();
 for(int j = 1; j<=list.size(); j++)
 {
            // Get entire page screenshot
            File screenshots = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshots);
            ImageIO.read(screenshots).getHeight();
            // Get width and height of the element
            int eleWidth =  Decision_Maker.getSize().getWidth();
            int eleHeight = Decision_Maker.getSize().getHeight();
            //Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
            BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(465, 190,eleWidth,eleHeight);
            ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "jpg", screenshots);

                //Scroll vertically to the element
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                js.executeScript("window.scroll (0, " + yPosition + ") ");
               
                yPosition = yPosition + eleHeight;  
                //wait for sometime
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                
                //File Location
                String location = "E:\\Automation\\Screenshots\\";              
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                    
                //capture screenshot
                FileUtils.copyFile(screenshots, new File (location + "img" + i + ".jpg"));
                Thread.sleep(3000L);
             }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create utils class to take screenshot and use it

```
  public static void TakeScreenshot(String filename) throws IOException
{
    File file= ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(file, new File("path to store screenshot" + filename + ".jpg"));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response but i thing you misunderstood my question i can capture the screenshots but my problem is the color of the screenshot which is not actual color, i want to capture screenshots as in actual color of the element not like the image i have attached

Comment: If you use take screenshots that is not capture black and white image , that will took original screen colour

Comment: try and let me know